# Interbase does not connect in Delphi 10.3.3 Rio

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, interbase

In the past, I have worked a lot with Delphi 7. I have two questions for Delphi 10.3:

1. Does the Interbase DB file have the extension `.IB` or `.GDB`, as in the past?
2. After having created a database with IBConsole, after having entered the `DatabaseName` property of the `TIBDatabase` component, I am never able to connect, I always receive the error "Unavailable Database". This also happens to me with the Delphi examples. I don't know what to think, maybe the problem is due to 32bit vs64bit of the system?

Comment: Check your system's services to see whether its actually the Interbase service which is running and not the Firebird one.  When I had the "unavailable database" problem, it turned out that some random piece of software had silently installed the Firebird service and so my app was inadvertantly using that, rather than the Interbase service to try to optn the database.

Comment: Thankyou but my english is very very bad. I make me understood: I cheked service and Interbase is in execution, Firebird don't exist. Tkanks

Answer (score 0):

InterBase definitely works in 10.3

1. Regarding File Extension for InterBase.
   You can name the file anything you want! InterBase use to use .gdb as the file extension, then Windows started using it for some files causing the OS to try and back those files up before use, and as you can imagine with large databases, that was a pain! So InterBase swapped to .ib as the default extension to avoid that issue.
2. Which version of Interbase are you using? Hopefully, the latest that comes with the product. It's unlikely to be a 32bit / 64bit issue. InterBase clients can connect to any InterBase server as it uses an over the wire protocol, separate to the OS version. You could be connecting to Linux from Windows, it really doesn't care.

The problem is likely to be InterBase isn't running, or the pathing is incorrect.
If you can connect in IBConsole, then you will be able to connect inside the IDE.
For the database name, just put in the local file path.
Depending on the settings, you might want to put in the full path including IP / server name e.g.
127.0.0.1:c:\mydatafolder\mydatabase.ib

InterBase uses server name or IP, a colon (as the separator) and then the file path on the machine indicated.

If you find you can't connect in IBConsole, restart InterBase using IB Server Manager.

If you are using an OLD version of InterBase, you can download the latest from inside RAD Studio by using Tools > Manage Platforms > Additional Options and selecting the developer edition from the list of options.